# Information about Tesla model 3's IPMSRM motor construction and torque production

Tags: motor

The Tesla model 3 has a AWD with IM at front and internal permanent magnet switched reluctance motor at its rear wheels. This IPMSRM motor has permanent magnets buried into the rotor in V pattern. These magnets also uses halbach array phenomenon. The halbach array produces magnetic field as in horse shoe magnet. Here two set are placed in V. These magnets help produce magnetic torque. The rotor's steel laminations contributes to the reluctance torque.

[image: this is the front view of IPMSRM]

My questions are:

1. Is this motor self starting? If yes, then how?
2. How are magnetic N S poles created by this 'V' shaped pair halbach array? please explain.
3. How is the reluctance torque produced?

Answer (score 3):

> Is this motor self starting? If yes, then how?

The motor is electronically controlled, so it doesn't need to be self starting in the usual sense. The controller energizes the stator at a low frequency. That creates a slowly rotating magnetic field that the rotor is able to follow. You can think of the motor as initially operating as a stepper motor. As the motor accelerates, the rate of acceleration is limited to keep the motor from "losing a step" or "pulling out of synchronism."

> How are magnetic N S poles created by this 'V' shaped pair halbach array? please explain.

Perhaps a diagram can be found on the internet.

> How is the reluctance torque produced?

The general principal is that the rotor tends to be pulled into alignment with the moving stator magnetic field such that the reluctance of the magnetic field path is minimized.

Comment: Regarding the halbach array. Tesla engineers have used two magnet bars and placed in V shape. Each bar is made of 4 magnets i.e the halbach array. The halbach array has N and S on one side as in horse shoe magnet. well then both the bars together give which pole?

Answer (score 1):

These magnets are used in a buried "V" shape arrangement in the rotor and for exactly this reason these magnets cannot be arranged in Halbach array. If the magnet bits inside in any of these magnets were in a Halbach pattern then there will be no resultant magnetic field (or just a very little) in the motor airgap, because the fields from each bits would short-circuit in the iron above the surface of the magnet blocks. In Halbach arranged magnet structures one side has no resultant field, here you can put iron, but it does not affect anything. Actually this allows to eliminate back iron... At he other side (the business side where we want a concentrated field), you cannot put iron, because see above  plus see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halbach_array - the flux distribution figures, the magnet poles would short immediately in the iron. Halbach array requires non magnetic material at the side where the magnetic poles are formed: for example can be used in surface magnet rotors or "air" (non magnetic) core motors.

I believe there confusion is coming from those lines on the body of these magnets. these lines can be just that - lines from the tooling, or indeed it can mean that smaller magnets are glued together, but not in Halbach - just regular, reinforcing parallelism, possibly glued before magnetizing the full block.